# Javascript to preview links

Tags: javascript, image-viewer, http, hyperlink

I would like to display a preview for http links that users could enter in my website.

Depending on the format/provider:

- links for `youtube` and `vimeo` would display the vignette of the videos
- audio links to `spotify` media would display album covers
- link to images resources (`imgur` and al. and links ending in `.jpg` or `.png`) would display a thumbnail (or return the image that I would resize).

I know I can write this myself by parsing the url for the different providers but I would hope to use/contribute an **existing javascript library** (not unlike [onebox](https://github.com/discourse/onebox) that is unfortunantely written for Ruby).

**Do you have a recommendation for such a library?**

Comment: At least part of that is covered by [Mousover Popup Image Viewer](http://w9p.co/userscripts/mpiv/), which is a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/Violentmonkey userscript (and thus JavaScript). Works great at least for images – not sure for the rest. But you at least could base on that. Taking a look cannot hurt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found many ways to preview those links.

#### [oEmbed](http://www.oembed.com/)

It's protocol that must be implemented by the content provider (youtube, twitter...) so you can use a unified API

There are big names of board: `flickr`, `youtube`, `vimeo`, `embedly`, `wordpress`, scribd... but also it misses the big elephants in the room `facebook`, `twitter`...

oEmbed has bindings for jquery, java, .net, ruby, php - well basically everyone

#### [NoEmbed](https://noembed.com/)

Aimed at fixing the oEmbed limitations and bringing a lot more content providers into the fold: `twitter`, `imgur`, `wikipedia`...

#### [Embedly](http://embed.ly/)

A convenient solution that comes at [a price](http://embed.ly/pricing) (a free tier is available).

> **note** I haven't used any this solutions yet, so I can't provide real world feedback.